# How to create a list with a dotted-pair using only list function in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Let's say I have the following list: `(A B . D)`.

How I would reproduce this only by using list function ?

`(list 'A 'B '. 'D)` is not working.

Comment: You have either set yourself an impossible task or misunderstood a task that was given to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. The constructor to create lists are `cons`. Proper lists are just the empty list or a chain of one or more `cons` where the last one has the empty list as the `cdr`. `list` only creates proper lists. Eg.
`(list 'a 'b 'c)` is a function that does `(cons 'a (cons 'b (cons c '())))`.

`(a b . d)` is created with `(cons 'a (cons 'b 'd))`. It is not a proper list since it is terminated by `d` and not `nil`. Thus it is impossible to create this structure with `list`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you are really trying to do here, but this seems to be exactly what [`list*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_.htm) is for:

```lisp
CL-USER> (list* 'a 'b 'd)
(A B . D)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  It is easy to see this by considering a simple two-argument version of `list`, which I'll call `lst`:

`lst` takes two objects `a` and `b` and constructs the following object: `(a . (b . nil))`, which looks like this:

[image: (list a b)]

It is then easy to see that there is no value of `b` which will result in the cdr of the last cons in such a chain being other than `nil` (aka `()`).  Therefore `lst`, and hence `list`, cannot construct a chain of conses in which cdr of the last cons is other than `nil`, which means it cannot construct a dotted list, since that is the definition of a dotted list.

Answer (score 0):

We can almost do this with `list`, but not quite. The point is that `list` insists on putting a `nil` at the end of the list, yet we want to have a non-`nil` value at the end.

We can therefore have a dotted term anywhere but at the end of the list.

I can offer you:

```
(list 'a '(b . c) 'd) ; has a normal list end of 'd -> 'nil
(list 'a '(b . c))    ; looks like b . c is at the end, but actually 'a is
```